# Select Box not filling properly in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select

I am creating a select box for a form using this in _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.select(:category_id,options_for_select(@cats)) %>
```

@cats is an array created in my controller like this:

```
@cats = []
categories.each do |c|
  @cats.push([c.full_name,c.id])
end
```

The select box is properly filled, and the selected foreign key is even properly saved to the database. The problem is, when I come back in my edit action, the select box is moved back to the first item in the list, not the one corresponding to category_id. Reading the documentation it seems like this should just magically work. How do I get it to select the proper value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `select` helper you just pass the choices not the full option tags like you would with the `select_tag` helper.  Try this instead

```
<%= f.select(:category_id, @cats) %>
```

Comment: Thank you! Rails can be really frustrating with so many similarly named functions doing distinctly different things.

Comment: Totally understand, I look up the apis on the form helpers at least once week.